# Multiplying number that is split into billions and remainder

Tags: logic, number-systems

I am working with 32 bit integers which have a maximum value of `2,147,483,647`, but am wanting to support higher numbers by having two variables (`billions` and `remainder`). I am trying to figure out a way where I can apply multiplication to the number as a whole while working with it split up.

Example 1: `billions=1`, `remainder=500000000`, `multiplier=2`. Expected output: `billions=3` and `remainder=0`.

Example 2: `billions=0`, `remainder=200000000`, `multiplier=5`. Expected output: `billions=1` and `remainder=0`.

Example 3: `billions=2`, `remainder=999999999`, `multiplier=5`. Expected output: `billions=14` and `remainder=999999995`.

I'm having difficulty coming up with a way to properly calculate what each of the values should be at the end when applying the multiplication. I am wanting to avoid loops to cut down on any performance hit with higher `multiplier`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want [Arbitrary Precision Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) where the digits of precision are arbitrary.

One way to do that would be to consider the integers in a Modular Residue Number system where you choose a base of primes $p_i$ (or even relatively prime numbers) and store the integer as the remainder modulo $p_i$. You can choose the primes such that the product $\prod_i p_i$ is greater than the largest integer you want to represent.

**Example:** $M = \{2, 3, 5\}$ will allow you to represent integers $0$ to $29$ (total of 30) since $2\times 3 \times 5 = 30$.

Since there are infinitely many primes, you can have as large a precision as you want.

[Arithmetic modulo residues is well defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system) and addition, subtraction, multiplication are very easy to do. Division requires computing the modular inverse which can be done using the Euclidean Algorithm.

You use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to convert the number from the Modular Residue Number form to decimal form.